# How to change the storage path from rrdtool on the Ganglia?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

How to change the storage path from rrdtool on the Ganglia?

For example: I have a default configuration in my file gmetad.conf, but I want to change to other storage. how to alter this path?

> Where gmetad stores its round-robin databases
>   default: "/var/lib/ganglia/rrds"
>   rrd_rootdir "/some/other/place"

I tried to change the rrd_rootdir, but doesn't work.

Thanks
Namir Rachid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you forgot few things. But I will elaborate with more details, but before that, you may need to stop gmetad daemon first:

Step 1: Create directory where you want to store rrdtool based data of ganglia

```
[root@ganglia-server ganglia-3.6.0]# mkdir -p /some/other/place/
```

Step 2: Make ganglia as the owner of this directory.

```
[root@ganglia-server ganglia-3.6.0]# chown -R ganglia /some/other/place/
```

Step 3: Provide appropriate permission also. You may test it otherwise.

```
[root@ganglia-server ganglia-3.6.0]# chmod -R 777 /some/other/place/
```

Step 4: Enable /some/other/place in gmetad.conf. Don't forget to remove pound symbol.

```
# Where gmetad stores its round-robin databases
# default: "/var/lib/ganglia/rrds"
rrd_rootdir "/some/other/place"
# rrd_rootdir "/some/other/place"
```

Step 5: Test if data is being written in /some/other/place in your gmetad log.

```
[root@ganglia-server ganglia-3.6.0]# gmetad/gmetad -d 5 -c /etc/ganglia/gmetad.conf
Going to run as user ganglia
Sources are ...
Source: [my cluster, step 15] has 1 sources
    127.0.0.1
xml listening on port 8651
interactive xml listening on port 8652
.......
.......
Updating host ganglia-server, metric cpu_steal
Created rrd /some/other/place/default/ganglia-server/cpu_steal.rrd
Updated rrd /some/other/place/default/ganglia-server/cpu_steal.rrd with value 1414567960:0.0
Updating host ganglia-server, metric load_one
Created rrd /some/other/place/default/ganglia-server/load_one.rrd
Updated rrd /some/other/place/default/ganglia-server/load_one.rrd with value 1414567960:0.01
```

Note: The gmetad executable may be at different location on your machine. Change the location as required to generate the log. In most of the cases, gmetad daemon is installed in "/usr/local/sbin/gmetad".

Step 6: Start the gmetad daemon now.

It worked for me. And, hopefully, it should work for you too.